# NPE при добавлении элементов в ChoiceBox через fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Не могу добавить элементы в ChoiceBox, при попытке ошибка NPE.
Добавлял любой другой элемент, с ним та же проблема, но до этого на других сценах всё работало, а тут создал новый Stage поверх другого и ничего теперь не работает, какой элемент я не добавил бы везде NPE.

**UPD:**

Попробовал не добавлять новый Stage. Ничего не работает всёравно.
Создал новый проект и там всё работает...
Как только добавил те fxml view снова эта же ошибка

**Контроллер**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

public ObservableList<String> choiceTableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("phone", "ram", "cpu", "display", "memory", "camera");

@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> chooseTable;

    @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    chooseTable.setItems(choiceTableList);

    }
}
```

**Вот fxml**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" 
        maxWidth="-Infinity" 
        minHeight="-Infinity" 
        minWidth="-Infinity" 
        prefHeight="187.0" 
        prefWidth="280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
        fx:controller="com.example.test.Controller">
        <Label layoutX="126.0" layoutY="41.0" text="Label" />
        <Button layoutX="65.0" layoutY="123.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="60.0" text="Next" />
        <Button layoutX="154.0" layoutY="123.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefWidth="60.0" text="Cancel" />
        <ChoiceBox fx:id="chooseTable" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="75.0" prefWidth="150.0"   />
</AnchorPane>
```

**Сама ошибка**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox.setItems(javafx.collections.ObservableList)" because "this.chooseTable" is null
at com.example.test/com.example.test.Controller.initialize(Controller.java:128)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
... 12 more
Exception running application com.example.test.Main
```

Comment: Как минимум нужно попробовать убрать private в строке `private ChoiceBox<String> chooseTable;`

Comment: @insolor, убрал, не помогло

Comment: а как подключаете fxml/Controller?